# Why doesn't Heroku see a file I create after I deploy?

Tags: php, git, heroku, yii, yii2

I want to set up asset compile and minification in Yii like Rails does.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

I was thinking of using a PHP minifier. I'd rather not have to manually compile and check in the assets into Git. However, even if it worked, Heroku doesn't appear to server new files that are not in Git. Why?

```
>heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.6857
~ $ cd web
cd web
~/web $ ls
ls
MySample.php  css          images          index.php  robots.txt
assets        favicon.ico  index-test.php  js
~/web $ echo hello > hello.txt
echo hello > hello.txt
~/web $ cat hello.txt
cat hello.txt
hello
~/web $ exit
exit
exit

$ curl -I http://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/hello.txt
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: I already know Heroku uses temporary file systems. I don't need the compiled assets saved, as they can be generated on the first request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason hello.txt was not found is because your curl -I request will be handled by a new instance of your application. To demonstrate, I can delete my index.php in bash, but when I use curl -I to retrieve it I get 200 OK.

```
$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.3070
~ $ cd web
~/web $ ls                    
index.php
~/web $ rm index.php      
~/web $ ls
~/web $ curl -I http://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/index.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Another way to show this it to open up two different bash connections, then run heroku ps

```
$ heroku ps
=== run: one-off processes
run.3070 (1X): up 2015/04/01 19:30:07 (~ 37m ago): `bash`
run.7783 (1X): up 2015/04/01 19:59:48 (~ 8m ago): `bash`
```

Those two processes are not going to share the ephemeral memory.

Comment: Oh `heroku run` creates a new instance... so minifying assets through the app and saving them to the temporary file system could still work, because they are saved on the instance that is running.